# Google ReCaptcha - Always reporting "Error for Site Owner: Invalid Site Key"

Tags: recaptcha

I have a total of 6 domains registered for my site key and secret key for ReCaptcha v2 (checkbox). However, only one of my domains (e.g. `domain.com`) is having issues. But others are fine.

I am not sure if there is a number of domain/subdomain restrictions applied via Recaptcha, otherwise - this error doesn't make any sense. Last time I checked, there should be about 50 (or near enough) domains that are allowed per Site/Secret Key setup.

Error I'm getting:

> "Error for Site Owner: Invalid Site Key"

Could anyone please help?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#recently-my-recaptcha-widget-started-displaying-invalid-site-key.-whats-happening ?

Comment: @maio290.       I think you've missed what I mentioned, There is no way this key is invalid. How come 5 other domains are working, and 1 isn't ? Invalid key means nothing should work when the key is exchanged.

Comment: Maybe this domain is using wrong protocol? Like http instead https, www but should be without, etc.

Comment: @LucasCosta      ah! You mean to say that the presented certificate (or the absence of it) can cause issues? I think localhost is the only valid case where not presenting certificate / communicating over unsecure layer is allowed for recaptcha. Don't know if that's a good explanation.

Comment: yes @ha9u63ar, further, did you check the "Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions"? If yes, try to uncheck it in order to validate if something related to the domain can being block the key.